# Mock a multiple funcion instance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

i´m trying to mock.setup  this multiple call sentence

```
 var response = await _email
            .To(notification.Email)
            .Subject(subjectEmail)
            .UsingTemplateFromEmbedded(templateEmail, new OrderConfirmEmailModel()
            {
                Name = notification.Name,
                NameReceiver = notification.NameReceiver,
                Lps = lps,
                Text = notification.Text
            }, GetType().Assembly)
            .SendAsync(cancellationToken);
```

i´m using moq and vs2019, how can i do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Already Solved, i had problems mocking the templateEmail, was a simple error, thanks!